# Google Analytics: Using custom variables to track growing values

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I believe custom variables in Google Analytics can only be used to track the distribution of different values for that variable over time.

Suppose I have a forum and want to track the total number of posts made in that forum. Could I track them over time with Google Analytics, too? And how?

Answer (score 1):

Custom Variables are a user-based dimension. So, traditionally, instead of measuring forum posts, they'd instead identify users who post on forums. That doesn't seem like what you're trying to measure.

Instead, you should consider looking at [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). Specifically, they allow for the tracking of 4 separate data points (per hit): 3 strings and a integer value.

So, you could use this to track *when* posts happen, or when comments happen on those posts, and then aggregate the values by whatever dimension you like using the API. You'd just need to bind the event to occur at the times you intend, with the data you want to track.

So, an example event call for you, tied to whenever someone posts a comment on a forum topic:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form Posts', 'Comment', topic_name, 1]);
```

You could then use the API to query particular views to tabulate whatever aspect of the event you want to aggregate. You can simulate those calls with the [Google Analytics API Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html). In this example, you could get number of Comments per day using Dimension set to `ga:date`, Metric set to `ga:totalEvents`, and then set the filter field to `ga:eventAction==Comment`